# Creating polymorphic lens

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass, haskell-lens

I am able to create a lens for the last field (`c`) in my data types by doing the follow:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}

data X1 a c = X1 { a' :: a, b' :: Int, c' :: c } 

data X2 a b c = X2 { a' :: a, b' :: b, c' :: c }

class HavingFieldC x cs ct where
  c :: Functor f => (cs -> f ct) -> x cs -> f (x ct)

instance HavingFieldC (X1 a) cs ct  where
  c = lens
    (\X1 { c' } -> c')
    (\X1 {..} v -> X1 {c' = v, ..})

instance HavingFieldC (X2 a b) cs ct where
  c = lens
    (\X2 { c' } -> c')
    (\X2 {..} v -> X2 {c' = v, ..})
```

Is there something similar I can do for fields `a` and `b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalize the definition of the `HavingField` class; in particular, you can express the relationship between the updated type variable and the record type using functional dependencies. This allows the update type variable to occur in any position; and it allows updates to monomorphic fields.

```
class FieldC k k' x x' | k x' -> k', k' x -> k, k -> x, k' -> x' where
  fieldC :: Functor f => (x -> f x') -> k -> f k'

instance (b ~ b0, b' ~ b0') => FieldC (X1 a b) (X1 a b') b0 b0' where ...
instance (b ~ b0, b' ~ b0') => FieldC (X2 c a b) (X2 c a b') b0 b0' where ...
```

You define instances in much the same way; note that some of the equality constraints are placed in the context to improve type inference. You can read the first instance above as `instance FieldC (X1 a b) (X1 a b') b b'`.

The classes for other fields are defined in exactly the same way; this is essentially the most general way to define a class for lenses (which should be more apparent if one notes that the type of `fieldC` is actually just `Lens k k' x x'`).

```
class FieldA k k' x x' | k x' -> k', k' x -> k, k -> x, k' -> x' where
  fieldA :: Functor f => (x -> f x') -> k -> f k'

class FieldB k k' x x' | k x' -> k', k' x -> k, k -> x, k' -> x' where
  fieldB :: Functor f => (x -> f x') -> k -> f k'
```

(Note: this too can be generalized to a single class with an additional parameter corresponding to the field name; this is probably outside the scope of this question).

Now it should be clearer how to write the instance declarations:

```
instance (x0 ~ Int, x1 ~ Int) => FieldB (X1 a c) (X1 a c) x0 x1 where ...
instance (b0 ~ b, b0' ~ b') => FieldB (X2 a b c) (X2 a b' c) b0 b0' where ...

instance (a ~ a0, a' ~ a0') => FieldA (X1 a c) (X1 a' c) a0 a0' where ...
instance (a0 ~ a, a0' ~ a') => FieldA (X2 a b c) (X2 a' b c) a0 a0' where ...
```

The only difference for monomorphic fields being that the field types are monomorphic types.

A simple test will show that the proper polymorphic types are assigned:

```
foo x = 
  let y = view fieldB x
  in set fieldA (2 * y) $ set fieldC (3 + y) x
```

You can ask GHCi for the inferred types at particular instantiations:

```
\x -> foo x `asTypeOf` X1{} :: X1 a b -> X1 Int Int
\x -> foo x `asTypeOf` X2{} :: Num a0' => X2 a a0' b -> X2 a0' a0' a0'
```

---

This general pattern can be found implemented e.g. [here](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.13/lens-labels-0.1.0.2/Lens-Labels.html#t:HasLens). This implementation is slightly more permissive; the `f` in `Functor f => ..` is a typeclass parameter instead of being universally quantified over. Depending on your specific use cases, this may or may not work for you.

Comment: What's more restrictive than what? How? I'm missing something.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm not sure what I had written there.. hopefully the edit makes more sense. Thanks for being such a diligent reader!

Comment: Do I need UndecidableInstances for this?

Comment: @VansonSamuel I think so (in order to have the type equality constraints in the context - with the simpler versions, i.e. `instance FieldC (X1 a b) (X1 a b') b b'`, you shouldn't need it).

Comment: @user2407038 I posted another questions on how to do the generalization you mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401763/how-to-simplify-calling-a-field-on-a-polymorphic-field-name-into-one-typeclass.  Would love to see a continuation of your answer.