# How to simplify calling a field on a polymorphic field name into one typeclass

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass, haskell-lens

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270018/creating-polymorphic-lens) I asked how a record field can be made polymorphic when using DuplicateRecordFields.  I got an excellent answer for this from  [@user2407038](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2407038/user2407038).  He answered the question to my initial spec providing one type class per field, but he mentioned that it could all be simplified into one typeclass.

> (Note: this too can be generalized to a single class with an additional parameter corresponding to the field name; this is probably outside the scope of this question).

I'm not sure how to go about doing this generalization. Does anybody have any ideas on how this can accomplished?

Comment: It's implemented as such in the library I linked in the previous answer ([here](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.13/lens-labels-0.1.0.2/Lens-Labels.html#t:HasLens) again)

Comment: I'm not sure how to create an instance to HasLens, and I was not able to find anybody else using it when I googled.

Comment: Taking the example from the previous question, instead of `instance (b ~ b0, b' ~ b0') => FieldC (X1 a b) (X1 a b') b0 b0'` you would have `instance (b ~ b0, b' ~ b0', Functor f) => HasLens "C" f (X1 a b) (X1 a b') b0 b0'`. Note that here `f` becomes a typeclass parameter; and there is an additional parameter representing the field name (a type level string, which can technically be anything you want, i.e. it doesn't have to relate in any way to the record field name).

Comment: How would I call it?  This doesn't seem to work: `lensOf $ (_ :: "C")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining such a class is easy enough

```
-- s has a field named field of type a and setting it to b turns the s into a t
class HasLens field s t a b | field s -> a, field t -> b, field s b -> t, field t a -> s where
  -- Fundeps are pretty common sense, and also appear in the library linked in the comments
  lensOf :: Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
  -- Not sure why the library linked above includes f in the class head...
```

You'll notice that `field` appears nowhere in `lensOf`'s type, so this class would be unusable as is, because the inferencer can never figure out what it should be. You have these options:

Old:

```
class HasLens name s t a b | ... where
  lensOf :: Functor f => Proxy name -> (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
  -- Or Proxy#, which has no runtime overhead, or forall proxy. Functor f => proxy name -> ...
```

The `Proxy` argument is a dummy; it is never used for anything except telling the compiler about `name`. Usage is unbearably ugly, though:

```
lensOf (Proxy :: Proxy "field")
-- or proxy#, or undefined
```

New:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}
```

Now you use explicit type applications to set `name` at the call site (also make sure that `name` is first in the class head, or else the order of type arguments will get messed up).

```
lensOf @"field"
```

Fuller example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes
           , DataKinds
           , FlexibleContexts
           , FlexibleInstances
           , FunctionalDependencies
           , NoMonomorphismRestriction
           , PolyKinds
           , ScopedTypeVariables
           , TypeApplications
#-}

import Control.Lens

class HasLens x s t a b | x s -> a, x t -> b, x s b -> t, x t a -> s where
  lensOf :: Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t

data Tup2 a b = Tup2 { _left2 :: a, _right2 :: b } deriving Show
data Tup3 a b c = Tup3 { _left3 :: a, _middle3 :: b, _right3 :: c } deriving Show

instance HasLens "left" (Tup2 a b) (Tup2 a' b) a a' where
  lensOf = lens _left2 $ \t x -> t { _left2 = x }

instance HasLens "left" (Tup3 a b c) (Tup3 a' b c) a a' where
  lensOf = lens _left3 $ \t x -> t { _left3 = x }

instance HasLens "right" (Tup2 a b) (Tup2 a b') b b' where
  lensOf = lens _right2 $ \t x -> t { _right2 = x }

instance HasLens "right" (Tup3 a b c) (Tup3 a b c') c c' where
  lensOf = lens _right3 $ \t x -> t { _right3 = x }

swap' :: forall xlr xrl l r xll xrr. (HasLens "left" xlr xrr l r, HasLens "right" xlr xll r l, HasLens "left" xll xrl l r, HasLens "right" xrr xrl r l) => xlr -> xrl
swap' x = x & lensOf @"left"  .~ x^#lensOf @"right" @xlr @xll @r @l
            & lensOf @"right" .~ x^#lensOf @"left"  @xlr @xrr @l @r

main = do out $ Tup2 5 6
          out $ Tup3 'l' 'm' 'r'
          out $ Tup2 "l" 'r'
          out $ Tup3 17 [5,10] "a"
  where out = print . swap'
```